# Get video properties (Frame Height, Width and Duration) from MediaElement

Tags: c#, wpf, video, mediaelement

I want to know how to get the value of video's height, width and duration. If its image i can change the `Uri` to bitmap and just use `imgUri.Height` but how about the video? I drop the file to the MediaElement and it play automaticaly with this code.

```
Uri videoUri = new Uri(videofile);
Video_MediaElement.Source = videoUri;
Video_MediaElement.Play();
```

that code works to shows video in MediaElement but i have no clue at all at getting Height, Width and also the Duration. How can i get that values?

Answer (score 4):

```
resulation.Text =  mediaelement.NaturalVideoWidth.ToString()+"x" +mediaelement.NaturalVideoHeight.ToString() +" px" ;
```

**Its like:**

**1080x720px**

Answer (score 1):

Try following.

```
mediaElement.NaturalDuration //to get video duration
mediaElement.NaturalVideoHeight //to get video height
mediaElement.NaturalVideoWidth //to get video width
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply, yes i tried this but the value keeps 0 i dont know why

Comment: actually its not the perfect answer to get the value instead of 0 MediaOpened event has to be raised.
try to start the video and then get the property values. if still remains same then let me know i will try to find some other solution.